# Am I using this integral sign correctly?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, notation, quantum-mechanics

I'm not sure how to use this integral symbol--but my guess is that it is used like so

$$\rlap{\sum}\int$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin x}x\ \mathrm{d}x=\pi$$

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin x}x=\pi$$

$$\rlap{\sum_{-\infty}^\infty}\int\ \frac{\sin x}x=\pi$$

I couldn't find anything on the internet except that it was something used in quantum mechanics (now you know why that tag is here). They said that it was used when a summation and integral notation could be used interchangedly. Thank you in advance

Note: I had to use a picture to show the mathematical equations because math stack-exchange doesn't support the notation.

Comment: Speaking as someone whose PhD thesis was about quantum field theory, I've never seen it.

Comment: The second equation should be a summation over $x$, not $n$.

Comment: If you want to render it in Mathjax (which doesn't support \sumint), you can do *\displaystyle\rlap{\sum}\int* which makes the \sum zero-width.

Comment: I advise never using that symbol.

Answer (score 4):

According to [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/5klfil/when_is_sumint_used/), it is used when it is ambiguous whether or not the operation is over a continuous distribution or a discrete one. Recall that integration is just a special kind of summation where we are working with a continuous argument. Thus, one might write $$\text{sumint}_{x=0}^\infty~f(x)$$
for a general definition: it tells the reader the definition works both in the discrete case and the continuous case, and so the reader should know which applies and use the definition accordingly.

What's a practical application of this? Mean value! The mean value for a discrete set is written

$$\left<x\right>=\sum_{x=0}^n x_i p_i$$

where $x_i$ is the $i^{th}$ outcome, $p_i$ is the probability of $x_i$ occuring, and $\left<x\right>$ is the mean outcome. In integral terms

$$\left<x\right>=\int_0^n xp(x)dx$$

So we can then, in general, say

$$\left<x\right>=\text{sumint}_{x=0}^n~xp(x)$$

This conveys all of the information that you need for both the integration and the summation, whichever applies. I have never seen this notation used before, but the above is seemingly how you should use it. I do not use it, but this is definitely a nice way of condensing two definitions into one.

Note, I haven't seen the notation before and online it is rarely referenced. I have omitted the $dx$ from the sumint because I do not think it belongs, but perhaps it does. This answer is to explain how it works, and I urge the community to please edit or comment in corrections to the notation as required.

Comment: In your first paragraph, I might phrase things in the other way:  summation is just a special kind of integration (that is, integration over the natural numbers with respect to counting measure).

Comment: Good answer but I can't help but feel the notation is cumbersome and adds very little. As you point out, integration is a continuous summation so $\sum_{n=1}^Nf(n)=\int_0^Nf\lceil t \rceil \ \mathrm{d}t$. So the sum-int operator could easily be expressed as $\int_0^Nf\circ g(t)\ \mathrm{d}t$ where $g(x)$ is an unknown function, either $x$ or $\lceil x \rceil$.

Comment: @xanderHenderson because integration is, at least here in Canada, defined as the limit of a summation, I would call it a special kind of summation. I've spoken to math colleagues who are in agreement with you; so I think both perspectives work.

Comment: @Kraig I was being somewhat facetious.  As you say, the *Riemann* integral is, by definition, the limit of Riemann sums (taken over partitions of the interval being integrated over).  If the only thing that a student knows is Riemann integration, then one can see an integral as a kind of "continuous sum".  On the other hand, from the point of view of measure theory, a sum is a special kind of integral, i.e. an integral taken over the natural numbers with respect to the natural counting measure on that space.

Comment: Assuming that your user profile is up-to-date, and you are still an undergraduate in physics, it is quite likely that you have not yet been exposed to measure theory.  How exciting!  You have something fun to look forward to in the near future!

Comment: To me, that symbol suggests the user does not really know what he/she is doing.

Answer (score 1):

As just a lowly mathematician, I would use the "Riemann-Stieljes" integral, $\int f(x)d\mu(x)$, where "$\mu(x)$" is a measure function.  If $\mu$ is a differentiable function then $\int f(x)d\mu(x)= \int f(x)\mu' dx$ and if $mu$ is a step function, $\mu(x)= 0$ if [$0< x\le 1$, $\mu(x)= 1$ if $1< x\le 2$, etc. then $\int f(x) d\mu= \sum_{n= 0} f(n)$

Comment: @uswr247327 your notation seems more prevalent and useful, but I suspect the notation in OP's question is something that is used frequently in a very niche branch of quantum physics. It seems as though the question's notation is more implicit, which would be useful if it is used frequently. However, OP's notation looks like a typographical error so I'd prefer yours if it is used infrequently.